# Uniformly bounded and lipschitz condition

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

İn
$
{C}\left[{a\mathrm{,}b}\right]
$

Show that the uniformly bounded set and for the same constant satisfies  lipschitz condition is compact .

Comment: İ I don't know I am thinking about arzela _ascoli

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right! Arzela-Ascoli is the right approach here.

If $\mathcal F \subset C[a,b]$ is your family of functions, and if all $f \in \mathcal F$ satisfy the condition
$$ |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | < \alpha |x_1 - x_2 |,$$
then the family $\mathcal F$ is certainly equicontinuous! Indeed, fixing an $\epsilon > 0$, we find that for all $f \in \mathcal F$,
$$ | x_1 - x_2 | < \frac \epsilon {\alpha} \implies |f(x_1) - f(x_2) | < \epsilon.$$

Since $\mathcal F$ is bounded and equicontinuous, Arzela-Ascoli tells you that $\mathcal F$ is totally bounded.

Note that $\mathcal F$ being totally bounded means that the *closure* of $\mathcal F$ is compact. So you still need the further assumption that $\mathcal F$ is closed.